# Can I move Windows to Bootcamp from Parallels?

Tags: windows-7, mac, osx-snow-leopard, boot-camp, parallels

Lately I'm playing with *Windows Phone 7* development, but I was in assumption that all development tool works well on Mac (Windows on Parallels) and later I found out that emulator doesn't work VMs!!

Now I set all my development environment on Parallels, I don't want to do it all again on bootcamp, is there any way I can move existing parallel setup to **BootCamp**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The drivers for parallels are not the real hardware drivers in the machine, they are virtual drivers. That is your biggest issue.

There may be an unsupported way to do this, such as using **Acronis True Image with Universal Restore** to convert the virtual hard drive file into an Acronis Image and then installing that image directly to your hard drive. The Universal Restore feature works about 70% of the time to remove the drivers and dependencies from an image, the other 30% it breaks the image. (Statistics from my experience with the software.)

There may be some Apple-created tool for accomplishing this task, but I am unaware of any and it doesn't seem likely.

Comment: I guess it better to spend few hours re-installing on bootcamp than fixing the causes raised after migration!